Cannot Start Local Server on GitHub Actions but Works Locally
I'm trying to start my local server on GitHub Actions using turbo dev --filter erp-web, but it fails. This command works perfectly on my local machine. Below is my GitHub Actions configuration file:
name: build-erp-test

on:    
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  start:
    name:  Install
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          submodules: true
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}      

      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v3
        name: Install pnpm
        with:
          version: 8
          run_install: false

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'
          cache: 'pnpm'

      - name: Install root dependencies
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Install turbo
        run: pnpm install turbo --global

      - name: Run erp server locally
        run: |
          turbo dev --filter erp-web &
          sleep 20

      - name: Display server status
        run: |
          echo "Checking if Turbo repo server is running..."
          curl -I http://localhost:5173 || (echo "Server did not start" && exit 1)

      - name: Verify if server is running
        run: |
          url="http://localhost:5173"
          http_status=$(curl -o /dev/null -s -w "%{http_code}\n" "$url")
          echo "HTTP Status: $http_status"

          # Check if the status code is 200 (OK)
          if [ "$http_status" -ne 200 ]; then
            echo "Website is down or not returning status 200"
            exit 1
          else
            echo "Website is up and running"
          fi

Problem:
When I run this workflow on GitHub Actions, the server does not start. The logs show that the turbo dev --filter erp-web command is executed, but the subsequent curl command indicates that the server is not running. No logs are being displayed on GitHub Actions, and I cannot see any files being generated in the GitHub Actions container.
What I've Tried:

I have verified that the same steps work on my local machine.
I added a sleep command to ensure there is enough time for the server to start.
I tried running turbo dev --filter erp-web without the & character at the end. In this case, the GitHub Actions workflow gets stuck, and no logging is displayed.

Additional Information:

There are no error messages from the turbo dev command in the GitHub Actions log.

Question:

How could force Github action to display logs from turbo?


Does increasing the sleep time helps ? Would this dependency work in this case : https://www.npmjs.com/package/start-server-and-test ?

Tried to increase the sleep time to even 60 but nothing.
